# Note taking software with sync and calendar

Tags: windows, android, note-taking, calendar

The "note-taking software" question has been asked many times, but this one is a bit different. I want a note taking software with the following features-

1) Sync across all the devices.

2) Must have desktop and android version. Having a web-based version would be a perk.

3) Must have a calendar in which one can mark important events on particular days (something like google calendar).

Comment: What should the notes be like? Is text only okay? In that case, the category of To do apps could fit your needs. (I personally use Apples Reminders app for this purpose; short To do like notes with optional alarms on them.)

Comment: Yes. Text only is fine. Well, I am looking more like a note taking app (primary) with a small calendar on side. It need not to remind me the event. Just showing the event on the calendar would do (e.g. google calendar).

Comment: I am very fond of standardnotes, which syncs very well and runs securely on everything.  But no calendar integration.  Let me just point out that in general calendar is not considered to be a function of notes, that's a todo-related function.  I use trello for project management, and it syncs with google calendar just fine.

Comment: Standardnotes is the best. I also use it. I agree that calendar is not a function of notes. So, I guess I have to use different software for note taking and marking important dates.

Comment: Last thing, do you know any such calendar app with sync and is available on all the platforms?